# Rails + Foundation without button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, zurb-foundation

I'd like to use foundation in my Rails4 app without the button style. 
I removed the import for the  button component but it is still styling the buttons.

```
@import
  "foundation/components/accordion",
  "foundation/components/alert-boxes",
  "foundation/components/block-grid",
  "foundation/components/breadcrumbs",
  "foundation/components/clearing",
  "foundation/components/dropdown",
  "foundation/components/forms",
  "foundation/components/grid",
  "foundation/components/inline-lists",
  "foundation/components/keystrokes",
  "foundation/components/labels",
  "foundation/components/magellan",
  "foundation/components/orbit",
  "foundation/components/pagination",
  "foundation/components/panels",
  "foundation/components/pricing-tables",
  "foundation/components/progress-bars",
  "foundation/components/reveal",
  "foundation/components/side-nav",
  "foundation/components/sub-nav",
  "foundation/components/switch",
  "foundation/components/tables",
  "foundation/components/tabs",
  "foundation/components/thumbs",
  "foundation/components/tooltips",
  "foundation/components/top-bar",
  "foundation/components/type",
  "foundation/components/offcanvas",
  "foundation/components/visibility";
```

When i use the web inspector to check where the styling is comin from it shows this link

```
/* line 197, /Users/thealchemist/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/foundation-rails-5.0.2.0/vendor/assets/stylesheets/foundation/components/_buttons.scss */
```

Is there something i'm missing?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you certain it is recompiling?  You may need to check each file and confirm that none of them are importing it.

Comment: Yeah, i've just checked everything again and i still can't see where it's coming from.

Comment: You don't by chance have a stray `@import "foundation"` lurking somewhere, do you?

Comment: Nope. Just rechecked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will find the answer you are looking for right [here](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/scss/foundation/components/_forms.scss)!

```
@import "foundation/components/forms"
```

also imports the button styles.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways you can fix this.

1. Just edit the css override file (app/assets/stylesheets/foundation_and_ovverides.css) and search for "button" and look for a section that starts like:

   //
   // BUTTONS
   //

   // $include-html-button-classes: $include-html-classes;

   // We use these to build padding for buttons.
   // $button-tny: rem-calc(10);
   // $button-sml: rem-calc(14);
   // $button-med: rem-calc(16);
   // $button-lrg: rem-calc(18);

Here you can uncomment lines and make the necessary changes to the button class. That way you can edit the button styling here.

1. Make sure that the button imports are not being called, open the page and view the source code from the browser and 'inspect element' to see where the button is getting the styling from. If it is definitely still being imported, try clearing out tmp/cache/assets/ folder.

Comment: I cleared those files but the styles are still there :(

Comment: why dont you create an override for .button in the application.scss file?

Comment: There's a minor design bug when overriding it. And it has to do with the button colour. That's what i've done anyways. I just thought i'd ask the ques. on here to see if anyone knows why. Plus i also want to remove other components.